# Laravel update checkbox responses when editing a data

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, eloquent-relationship

Below is the evaluation edit form. When I edit and update the code sometimes updates the data in score_evalauation_responses table and sometimes does not updates. The edit form is

```
                         @foreach ($scoreEvaluations as $scoreEvaluation)
                                @php
                                    $response = $feedback->responses->where('score_evaluation_id', $scoreEvaluation->id)->first();
                                    $isChecked = $response && $response->response > 0;
                                @endphp
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="form-check-input score" type="checkbox"
                                                value="{{ $scoreEvaluation->marks }}"
                                                name="response-{{ $scoreEvaluation->id }}"
                                                id="score-{{ $scoreEvaluation->id }}" {{ $isChecked ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                                            <label class="form-check-label">{{ $scoreEvaluation->name }}</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
```

The update method is

```
public function update(Request $request, QCFeedback $feedback)
    {
        $checkedScores = explode(',', $request->areChecked);
        $unCheckedScores = explode(',', $request->areUnchecked);

        $feedback->update([
            'evaulated_by' => $request->evaulated_by,
            'record_id' => $request->record_id,
            'call_duration' => $request->call_duration,
            'audit_date' => $request->audit_date,
            'transcribe_date' => $request->transcribe_date,
            'cru_agent_detail_id' => $request->cru_agent_detail_id,
            'audit_type_id' => $request->audit_type_id,
            'elevation_audit_id' => $request->elevation_audit_id,
            'areChecked' => json_encode($checkedScores),
            'areUnchecked' => json_encode($unCheckedScores),
            'score' => $request->score,
            'status' => $request->status,
            'complaince' => $request->complaince,
        ]);

        foreach ($request->all() as $key => $item) {
            $key = explode('-', $key);
            if (count($key) > 1) {
                if ($key[0] == 'response') {
                        //$scoreEvaluation = \DB::table('score_evaluation_responses')
            //->where('qc_feedback_id', $feedback->id)
                  //->where('score_evaluation_id', $key[1])
            //->update([
                        //'qc_feedback_id', $feedback->id,
                        //'score_evaluation_id', $key[1],
                        //'response' => $item
                  //]);
                              
                    $scoreEvaluation = ScoreEvaluationResponse::where('qc_feedback_id', $feedback->id)
                        ->where('score_evaluation_id', $key[1])
                        ->first();
                    $scoreEvaluation->update([
                        'response' => $item,
                    ]);
                              
                }
            }
        }

        Session::flash('success', 'Feedback Updated successfully!');
        return redirect()->route('qc-feedback-audits.index');
          
    }
```

The form updates one or two time. When I edit the response values again and submit, they are not updated. How to fix it?

I have tried following methods for updating the score_evaluation_responses table:

```
foreach ($request->all() as $key => $item) {
            $key = explode('-', $key);
            if (count($key) > 1) {
                if ($key[0] == 'response') {
                        $scoreEvaluation = \DB::table('score_evaluation_responses')
            ->where('qc_feedback_id', $feedback->id)
                  ->where('score_evaluation_id', $key[1])
            ->update([
                        'qc_feedback_id', $feedback->id,
                        'score_evaluation_id', $key[1],
                        'response' => $item
                  ]);
                              
                }
            }
        }
```

Another way:

```
foreach ($request->all() as $key => $item) {
        $key = explode('-', $key);
        if (count($key) > 1) {
            if ($key[0] == 'response') {
                $scoreEvaluationId = $key[1];
                $response = $feedback->responses()->where('score_evaluation_id', $scoreEvaluationId)->first();
                if ($response) {
                    $response->update([
                        'response' => $item
                    ]);
                } else {
                    $response = new ScoreEvaluationResponse([
                        'score_evaluation_id' => $scoreEvaluationId,
                        'response' => $item
                    ]);
                    $feedback->responses()->save($response);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the issue was not solved